# Find intersection of two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-programming

I have two lines and i have coordinates of starting point and ending point of both lines.
I need to find the intersection point on four different case.

These are the four cases:-

From image below, I have $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),(x_4,y_4)$ i need to find $(x,y)$.

Is there any single equation for all of these cases or different?

[image: 1]

Comment: Find the equation of both lines using both the point and then solve the two linear equations you will get to find the point of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

There is one equation for all four cases.

The vector equation for the first line is

$(x, y) = (x_1, y_1) + t ( x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1 ) = P_1 + t V_1 $

And the equation fo the second line is

$ (x, y) = (x_3, y_3) + s ( x_4 - x_3, y_4 - y_3) = P_3 + s V_2 $

To find the intersection point, set $ P_1 + t V_1 = P_3 + s V_2 $

Then you have the linear system

$ A u = B $

where

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} V_1 && -V_2 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} a && b \\c && d \end{bmatrix} $

where $a = x_2 - x_1, b = x_3 - x_4 , c = y_2 - y_1, d = y_3 - y_4 $

$u = \begin{bmatrix} t \\ s \end{bmatrix}$

$B = P_3 - P_1 = \begin{bmatrix} e \\ f \end{bmatrix} $

where $e = x_3 - x_1 , f = y_3 - y_1 $

Solve the system for $u$ ,

$u = A^{-1} B = \dfrac{ 1}{a d - b c} \begin{bmatrix} d && - b \\ -c && a \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e \\ f \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore,

$ t = u_1 = \dfrac{ e d - b f }{ a d - b c } $

$ s = u_2 = \dfrac{ - c e + a f }{a d - bc } $

Now you can compute the intersection point as

$ I = P_1 + t V_1 $

i.e.

$I = (x, y) = (x_1 + t (x2 - x_1) , y_1 + t (y_2 - y_1) )$

You can also use

$ I = P_3 + s V_2 $

Comment: I have some doubts, what is t,s . Also i need a solution to use inside my computer program.

Comment: $t$ and $s$ are parameters (i.e. real numbers).  I'll update the solution to make it suitable for your computer program.